# Swift Selector caseInsensitiveCompare

Tags: arrays, sorting, selector, swift

how is the Code of

```
@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)
```

in Swift?
I try to sort an Array of Dictionary's

```
 NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true, selector: Selector(???))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3

```
NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))
```

Swift 2

```
NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true, selector: "caseInsensitiveCompare:")
```

Comment: For newer versions of swift use, NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "name", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))